# maven force rebuild of dependent projects (build dependencies first)

Tags: maven

I have a multimodule maven project. the service module depends on domain module using dependency tag. Every time i build the service module, i want it to automatically build the domain module and pick up the most recent domain module from local repository. How can I do it. Right now it pick from the local repository but that may not be the latest copy.

I build the project from my service module dir and not from the parent directory. Because my parent module has lot of other submodules that I am not interested in building.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One thing you can possibly do is to build the `service module` from the `parent directory` with the following parameters.

```
mvn compile -pl service-module -am
```

What this does is builds only the `service module`, along with its dependant modules (which would include the `domain module`).

The options are described by `mvn --help` (Maven 2.2.0):

```
   -am,--also-make
          If project list is specified, also build projects required by the list

   -pl,--projects <arg>
          Build specified reactor projects instead of all projects
```

Comment: Do you happen to know how to execute such command in the Eclipse IDE ?

Comment: It's too late for you... but just put everything except for `mvn` in the `goals` field. ie. `compile -pl service-module -am`